# PDFmake table dynamic data

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdfmake

I am using PDFmake to create pdf file, I want to add dynamic data in the table butt the body display empty.

this one works when I print [0] but I have lots of dynamic data

```
 getData(installation, request) {
          const phases = {
            layout: {
              hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
                return 0.45;
              },
              vLineWidth: function(i, node) {
                return 0.45;
              }
            },
            table: {
              dontBreakRows: true,
              widths: ["30%", "10%", "60%"],
              body: [
                [

                  {
                    text: installation.phases[0].text,
                    style: "cell"
                  },
                  { text: installation.phases[0].status},
                  {
                    text: this.getFeedback(installation.phases[0]),
                    style: "commentCell"
                  }
                ],
              ]
            }
          };
          console.log(phases);
          return phases;
      }
```

but If I use this one it create table body empty.

```
  getData(installation, request) {
installation.phase.forEach(value =>{
          const phases = {
            layout: {
              hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
                return 0.45;
              },
              vLineWidth: function(i, node) {
                return 0.45;
              }
            },
            table: {
              dontBreakRows: true,
              widths: ["30%", "10%", "60%"],
              body: [
                [

                  {
                    text: data.text,
                    style: "cell"
                  },
                  { text: data.status},
                  {
                    text: this.getFeedback(data),
                    style: "commentCell"
                  }
                ],
              ]
            }
          };
          console.log(phases);
          return phases;
});
}
```

What could be wrong here? I have tried but cannot find solution

Comment: You set the text of the table body to data.text, data.status and this.getFeedback(data) but where does this "data" coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this was your goal.

I have rewritten your code and created JSON structure (const phases) for PDF and then dynamically filled table.body with JSON array consisting of rows. I did not try to run it, so there might be some compile errors. Hope this helps!

```
getData(installation, request) {
  const phases = {
    layout: {
      hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
        return 0.45;
      },
      vLineWidth: function(i, node) {
       return 0.45;
      }
    },
    table: {
     dontBreakRows: true,
     widths: ["30%", "10%", "60%"],
     body: []
    }
   }

   installation.phases.forEach(value => {
    phases.table.body.push([
     { text: value.text, style: 'cell' },
     { text: value.status, },
     { text: this.getFeedback(value), style: 'commentCell' }
    ])
   })

  console.log(phases)
  return phases
}
```